# How to check if a program was statically compiled in c

Tags: c, linux, static, elf

How would you able to check if another program was statically compiled without using `system()` or `stat()` or any other `shell execution commands`

Comment: You _can_ do this by opening the file and parsing the ELF headers by hand.  Are you allowed to use a library?

Comment: no, as few as library as possible, im trying to keep it as native as possible

Comment: If you are attempting this as some sort of security measure, it is likely impossible in general, as a program could contain no overt call to `system` or other concerning routines or system calls in its machine instructions but could construct such instructions during execution in various ways.

Comment: Maybe you could do open the file in binary and search for strings that are part of the standard library and unlikely to be in a user application?  I'm thinking "Undefined error" in `perror()` and the like.

Comment: As noted in the comments on my answer, it's not clear how to parse the question. Can you please clarify what you're asking so I know if my answer is meaningful as written or should be replaced or deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming ELF, parse the Ehdr to find the program headers (Phdrs), then look for one of type `PT_INTERP`. The program is static linked if this program header is absent. The relevant data structures can be found in `elf.h`.

Comment: Does that distinguish between `int main(void) { system("foo"); }` and `int main(void) {}`, which is what I think OP wants?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: On furthere reading, I'm not clear on how to parse OP's question. I thought OP was asking for a way to answer "is this binary file statically linked?" without invoking a command like `file` or `readelf` to perform this check. If OP wants to know if the program invokes commands or operates on the filesystem, and the program is from unknown and potentially malicious source, the answer is simply that **there is no way to do this**.

Comment: im asking if another program was compiled statically without using system() in the primary program that im writing, the program im writing cannot execute shell commands like system("file path/to/file");

Comment: @JordanMiller: OK. In that case my answer applies.